# Which scheme is best for storing country, region and city data

Tags: mysql

I need to store information about countries, regions and cities. Which schema should I use:

**Tables:**

1. country (id, code, name);
2. region (id, ctry_id, code, name);
3. city (id, rgn_id, code, name).

> ```
> | id | code | name |
> | 1  | US   | USA  |
> ```

---

> ```
> | id | ctry_id | code | name  |
> | 1  | 1       | TX   | Texas |
> ```

---

> ```
> | id | rgn_id | code | name   |
> | 1  | 1      | DS   | Dallas |
> ```

**OR**

1. location (id, pid, type, name);

> ```
> | id | pid | type | name   |
> | 1  | 0   | ctry | USA    |
> | 2  | 1   | rgn  | Texas  |
> | 3  | 2   | cty  | Dallas |
> ```

---

> Which approach is better?

Comment: The first approach is probably what you want in practice.  Though, the second approach does have the advantage that it lets you define any hierarchy for an address.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Right now I'm using first approach, but I'm considering to use second one, and that's why I'm asking that question.

Comment: If the address schema is fixed and regular, e.g. every address is always in the US, then I see nothing wrong with the first approach.  If the schema could be more varied, then the second approach looks more attractive.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes there'll more countries, Thanks a lot! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it depends what you're going for really.

I would guess that option 2 may be more performant in speed terms, but at the cost of the table ending up quite confusing with lots of entries. I would recommend perhaps restricting the type field to a list of known types and only altering when you need to with this approach. Also consider how this would feel to someone with little knowledge of the data needing to maintain this.

The first option may not be as fast, but will be more structured, and with tables that are appropriately named. This would probably be the way that you're colleagues unfamiliar with the data would thank you for.

I would give option 1 a go, and if it meets your performance needs then go with that one. If it's too slow for you try the second.

Personally, I prefer the first. Sometimes a slight hit in performance is worth readability. Other times not.

Good luck in your choice.

Comment: Why would the first approach be slower than the second?

Comment: Thank you very so much! I appreciate it! )))

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not necessarily saying it will be slower, but I'm using the general advice that sometimes databases structured in a relational way may have constraints, that in some situations may be slower than the NoSQL-styled approach outlined in 2. As I say in my answer, my preference is choice 1 because it seems to be better structured. However if performance is important and you are aware of the maintenance costs, then option 2 may perform better, but as with anything, performance tests should be carried out to confirm. Sorry if this wasn't clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say schema 1 is relational and that is what mysql expect and i think would perform better. but if you would ever need to work with noSqls like couchdb, schema two is how it works and it good for queries but not for generating reports.